# mobile vs dektop authentication with client certificate HTTPS

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, https, x509certificate

Is there a different between mobile-authentication and desktop-authentication via certificate and https?
And when, how to solve mobile authentiction with certificate?

We try to accomplish a connection to a site eg. https: example.com and authenticate the user via certificate.
Before setup a CA and generate necessary certificates.

C# code from login site:

```
    var x509 = new X509Certificate2(this.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);
    var chain = new X509Chain(true);
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Offline;
    chain.Build(x509);
```

that works great with IE desktop browser, and we can log every certificate information.
**edit:**
It´s not working with firefox and there is no question about to choose a local certificate - same behavior as mobile.

Try the same url via mobile eg: iPhone or Windowsphone - nothing can read from the certificate.

**Solution:**
as @Sean Baker said, install your CA cert as well on mobile. Thats the reason for me to upvote his answer as the right answer for this question.

Have a look at the webservers certificate. in my case, i have created the certificates on microsoft server and used a copy from "webserver" template, so that it was possible for me to export the certificate with a private key,
cause that made it easier to deploy.

here is a url that point me in the right direction:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931351

The login with firefox is working as well - you have to install your personal certificate within the fF administration. After that, you will be prompted to choose that certificate when opening the url via https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in the protocols, but installation of the certificates on the devices and later access to them is much different.  How did you install the device certificate on Windows, and how on the iPhone?

Comment: certificate on windows over my-dc/certsv, 
in mobile via email

Comment: And do you see the private certificate in the iPhone if you go to Settings->General->Profiles?  Does it show as a verified Identity Cert?

Comment: i can see the private certificate in the iPhone - yes, but it is shown as "not approved". Sure, it is selfsigned certificate from a private ca.

Comment: Did you also install the private CA on the phone?  If not, can you try?

Comment: Good hint, after installing the private CA on the iPhone, both the CA and the privateCert are shown as approved in iPhone. Unfortunately i can`t grab the information at login as well.